# Missing polygons in games

Tags: graphics

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLoPg.png)
[image]

I don't know what the problem is, but in any game, there are missing polygons, my pc is old and low end, and intel celeron j1800 with integrated graphics, This problem appears on ubuntu 20.04 and other flavors, I'm pretty noob about technical things in the os, so if you decide to help me, please try being detailed